# Angularjs dom load ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on angularjs. I created a scrlipt. When I started applciation on browser, appearing like this,

[image]

and a little later coming result,

[image]

```
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        Search By Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="searchTerm" />
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:searchTerm | orderBy:name">{{cust.name}} - {{cust.city | uppercase}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                { name: 'John', city: 'Barcelona' },
                { name: 'Scott', city: 'Madrid' },
                { name: 'Jennifer', city: 'Seattle' },
                { name: 'Mike', city: 'Atalanta' }
            ];
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I want to see result after loaded everything like second Picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) directive, which keeps Angular templates hidden until your application is ready:

```
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        Search By Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="searchTerm" />
        <ul data-ng-cloak>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:searchTerm | orderBy:name">{{cust.name}} - {{cust.city | uppercase}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                { name: 'John', city: 'Barcelona' },
                { name: 'Scott', city: 'Madrid' },
                { name: 'Jennifer', city: 'Seattle' },
                { name: 'Mike', city: 'Atalanta' }
            ];
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**Edit:** This will only have the desired effect if you load Angular in the `<head>` section of your HTML (or before you use the `ngCloak` directive). If you still want to load Angular at the end of the document, you need to include this CSS before your templates:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```